# Cloudera Hadoop Extended Acl's not working

Tags: hadoop

Have been working on this for a week now, here is my issue. I have setup my cluster CDH5 with security enabled using MIT Kerberos. I am now trying the extended ACL's and has done all the necessary changes responsible to set it up but it doesn't work , here is the summary in commands.

```
      [root@dn01 ~]# kinit hdfs
      Password for hdfs@VT2.HADOOP.BA.SSA.GOV: 
      [root@dn01 ~]# hdfs dfs -ls /vt2/testdata/dcus
      Found 2 items
      -rwxr-----   3 hdfs systems       3949 2016-03-16  
      16:13 /vt2/testdata/dcus/XXXX.JSONSEQ
      drwxr-----+  - hdfs systems          0 2016-03-18  
      15:57 /vt2/testdata/dcus/nn
      [root@dn01 ~]# hdfs dfs -getfacl /vt2/testdata/dcus
          # file: /vt2/testdata/dcus
          # owner: hdfs
          # group: systems
          user::rwx
          group::r--
          group:developers:r--
          mask::r--
          other::---
    [root@dn01 ~]# kdestroy
    [root@dn01 ~]# kinit 419650
    Password for 419650@VT2.HADOOP.BA.SSA.GOV: 
    [root@dn01 ~]# hdfs dfs -ls /vt2/testdata/dcus
    ls: Permission denied: user=419650, access=READ_EXECUTE,   
    inode="/vt2/testdata/dcus":hdfs:systems:drwxr-----:group::r--,group:developers:r--
    [root@dn01 ~]# id 419650
    uid=1502(419650) gid=1504(419650) groups=1504(419650),1503(systems)
    [root@dn01 ~]# kinit 815677
    Password for 815677@VT2.HADOOP.BA.SSA.GOV: 
    [root@dn01 ~]# hdfs dfs -ls /vt2/testdata/dcus
    ls: Permission denied: user=815677, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/vt2/testdata/dcus":hdfs:systems:drwxr-----:group::r--,group:developers:r--
    [root@dn01 ~]# id 815677
    uid=1500(815677) gid=1500(815677) groups=1500(815677),1502(developers)
```

I can only access the directory if I authenticate as hdfs which is the owner of that dir otherwise not even though if that user is a member of the group which has access to the directory in question as seen in "getfacl" command.

Comment: Comment #1: with `id` you are looking at *Linux* groups on the *local* machine. With `hdfs groups` you would be looking at *Hadoop* groups on the *NameNode*, and that's the ones that matter. Because that account may not have the same groups on the NameNode machine, and because the mapping is not necessary 1-to-1 *(could be overriden by a custom JAR, for example)*

Comment: Comment #2: so you have defined an ACL on `/vt2/testdata/dcus/`, but does your group have access to directories `/vt2/` and `/vt2/testdata/`? *(thou shalt not believe error messages, they art missleasing somtimes...)*

Comment: Comment #3: if you want to browse a directory, privilege `x` may be appropriate. After all, the error message explicitly complains about not having READ_**EXECUTE**. In plain sight, like the proverbial yellow elephant in the room.

Comment: That being said, I strongly suggest that you experiment with Linux ACLs first, then you can apply your new skills on HDFS. Both are POSIX-compliant *(except for the nasty bug about "umask" precedence https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6962)* and use very similar syntax

Comment: Thanks Samson : For comment 1 # I have already made all the groups on the namenode which are present on the rest of the machines and it works but its only extended acl's that don't work. Comment#2: I have tested and added the extended acl's to the root of the said dir(/vt2) as follows but still no luck:

Comment: root@dn01 ~]# hdfs dfs -setfacl -m default:group:developers:r-x /vt2
    [root@dn01 ~]# hadoop fs -getfacl /vt2
   # file: /vt2
   # owner: hdfs
   # group: systems
   user::rwx
   group::r-x
   other::---
  default:user::rwx
  default:group::r-x
  default:group:developers:r-x
  default:mask::r-x
  default:other::---
  [root@dn01 ~]# kinit 419650
  Password for 419650@VT2.HADOOP.BA.SSA.GOV: 
  [root@dn01 ~]# hadoop fs -getfacl /vt2/testdata/dcus
  # file: /vt2/testdata/dcus
  # owner: hdfs
  # group: systems
  user::rwx
  group::r-x
  other::---

Comment: [root@dn01 ~]# hadoop fs -ls /vt2/testdata/dcus
Found 2 items
-rwxr-x---   3 hdfs systems       3949 2016-03-16 16:13 /vt2/testdata/dcus/ATS.PRD.R3.HISTBU1.DCUS.JSONSEQ
drwxr-x---   - hdfs systems          0 2016-04-22 10:46 /vt2/testdata/dcus/nn
[root@dn01 ~]# hadoop fs -ls /vt2/testdata/dcus/nn
Found 1 items
-rwxr-x---   3 hdfs systems       3949 2016-04-22 10:46 /vt2/testdata/dcus/nn/ATS.PRD.R3.HISTBU1.DCUS.JSONSEQ

Comment: [root@dn01 ~]# kinit 815677
Password for 815677@VT2.HADOOP.BA.SSA.GOV: 
[root@dn01 ~]# id 815677
uid=1500(815677) gid=1500(815677) groups=1500(815677),1502(developers)
[root@dn01 ~]# hadoop fs -ls /vt2/testdata/dcus/nn
ls: Permission denied: user=815677, access=EXECUTE, inode="/vt2":hdfs:systems:drwxr-x---
[root@dn01 ~]# hadoop fs -ls /vt2
ls: Permission denied: user=815677, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/vt2":hdfs:systems:drwxr-x---

Comment: comment#3 : I already added the execute permission as shown in the code but still not working.

Comment: What I see from your code snippets is that you set a **default** ACL on `/vt2/` -- i.e. a rule that *future sub-directories and files* will inherit that permission. But that does not apply to directory `/vt2/` itself.

Comment: `hdfs dfs -setfacl -m group:developers:r-x,default:group:developers:r-x /vt2`